# HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() is null in rest resource

Tags: rest, jersey, glassfish-4.1

I have a backend REST application running in glassfish 4.1.
In this simple test resource I want to log the remote address:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("test")
@RequestScoped
public class TestResource {

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestResource.class.getName());

  @Context
  private UriInfo context;

  public TestResource() {
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String getText(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    LOG.info("TEST - REMOTE ADDRESS: " + req.getRemoteAddr());
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

I have nothing "strange" and no proxy (so no "x-forwarded-for" and so on), but when I access the resource I *always* get null as remote address.

I have googled a lot and tried different solutions with no luck (ie: implementing a filter doesn't work: inside the filter request.getRemoteAddr() is always null).

Comment: it is not always possible to extract the client address from the request. I would say if it is not there then, the client is not sending this info.

Comment: what do you mean with "the client is not sending this info"? rest is http, http sit on top of tcp, etc, there's no way to have an http connection with no client/server addresses. 
are you implying java is not using that information but get the client address from other source? if yes, can you point me where?

Comment: @moretti.fabio hello, have you found any solution ? I am facing exact same issue, REST call always gives me null value while SOAP works.

Comment: @PriyankaW lot of time passed, I don't remember, but I can tell you that actually using spring and jax rs I do have that info in the http request.